# Posting data on django api from retrofit 2 android

Tags: android, django-rest-framework, retrofit2

I am working on a project which will retrieve and send data to server through django api. I am facing problem to POST data through the api. My codes are given below. Executing this code give 401 Error in response in android studio but the api works fine in postman or web browser. TIA for the help.

Class to set retrofit instance:

```
public class ApiClient {
   public static final String BASE_URL = "https://myapilink.com/";

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient() {

    final OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            // Request customization: add request headers
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", "auth-value"); // <-- this is the important line

            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });


    final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();

                    // Request customization: add request headers
                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNA=="); // <-- this is the important line

                    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            })
            .build();

    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Retrofit interface:

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("/api/auth/login/")
Call<LoginModel> getLoginResponseWithRetrofit(@Body LoginBody loginBody);
}
```

LoginBody model:

```
public class LoginBody {

String email;
String password;

public LoginBody(String email, String password){
    this.email=email;
    this.password=password;
 }

}
```

Main api calling method:

```
public void postDataWithRetrofit(String email, String password){

    //modelFromIDProvider.add(InternalDataProvider.getInstance().getAgentDataModelList());


    int selectedPosition,id;

    LoginBody loginBody = new LoginBody(email, password);

    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<LoginModel> call;

    Map<String, String> formData = new HashMap<>();
    formData.put("email", email);
    formData.put("password", password);

    Log.d(TAG,"formdata "+formData.toString());

    //call = apiService.getLoginResponseWithRetrofit(email, password);

    call = apiService.getLoginResponseWithRetrofit(loginBody);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginModel>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginModel> call, Response<LoginModel> response) {
            Log.d(TAG,"isSuccessful "+response.isSuccessful()+" code "+response.code());

            Log.d(TAG,"Data from response : "+response.body());
            if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                return;
            }

            LoginModel responseModel = response.body();
            InternalDataProvider.getInstance().setLoginDataModel(responseModel);

            Log.d(TAG,"Data from response : "+response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginModel> call, Throwable t) {
            if(call.isCanceled()){
                Log.d(TAG," call cancelled "+t.toString());
                return;
            }

            Log.d(TAG," inside onFailure "+t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are mixing up retrofit 1 and retrofit 2 on rest adapter and api methods.  use either one.

Comment: Same code works for me in some of my other projects.

Comment: pl provide postman request and response. and i also remove one splash in login api calling because already base url have backsplash. check your full url in request time.

Comment: This is the response I receive in android code.
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized, url=https://mylink.com/api/login/}